# What does this mean in Javascript: a = a | b

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 0;
var c = 3;

function myFunction(b) {
    a = a | b;
    return (a == c);
}
```

Saw this today, what does "a = a | b" do?

Comment: this has to be a duplicate, search for "bitwise or".

Comment: [Javascript operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: I think you should learn some very (very) basic javascript before asking such questions.
but it mean (a or b), where an integer is true if it's different than 0.

Comment: I really don't understand all of the downvotes here, sure it is a duplicate but it is very hard to get good search results on `|`.

Comment: @Gal - *ahem*, be careful who you chastise about 'basic javascript'. `|` is the bitwise, not the logical operator

Comment: @F.J - But it is very easy to google "Javascript operators" then `CTRL+F` look for `|`

Comment: @F.J - the downvotes probably come from the fact that "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: I'm so sorry for the duplicate, but like @F.J said, I searched around for this, but it is really hard to find good search results with |.

Comment: @MartinSmith I did exactly that. It's not in http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp
nor
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Anyway, thanks for those who provided the helpful answers, and for those who down voted this, try search yourself if u think its easy to look for symbols like this which are used in many pages as separators.

Comment: @Jin - As a rule of thumb always skip the w3schools links and go straight to MDN.

Comment: @gal you should read the question properly, it is | not ||.

Comment: @martinsmith noted with thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `bitwise-or` operation and asigning the result to a.

Example:

if a=5 and b=4 then corresponding bits of their binary representation is operated by an `or-operation`.

```
    a=101
    b=100

    a=a|b=101|101=101=5;
```

Comment: This is a frequent, exact duplicate. Please do not feed it answers.

Comment: @PaulSasik I see, ok I've been only for a month I don't know :)